# how to plot a red dot?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-feynman, feynman

I wanna plot a feynman diagram as below. I plotted the diagram but don't know how to add the red dot. my latex code is below. Anyone can give me a favor?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[compat=1.1.0]{tikz-feynman}
\begin{document}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{feynman}
\vertex (a) {\(b\)};
\vertex [below= 2.4cm of a] (b){\(g\)};
\vertex [below right=of a] (c);
\vertex [ right=of c] (d) ;
\vertex [below right=1.0cm of d] (f3);
\vertex [below right=1.0cm of f3] (f4);
\vertex [above right=1.3cm of f3] (f5) {\(h\)};
\vertex [above right=1.3cm of d] (fw){\(W^{-}\)};

\diagram* {
(a) -- [fermion] (c) -- [fermion] (d),
(b) -- [gluon] (c),
(d) -- [fermion,edge label'=\(t\)] (f3) --[fermion,edge label'=\(t\)] (f4),
(f3)-- [scalar] (f5),
(d)--[boson] (fw),
};
\end{feynman}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}`
```

[image]

Comment: just add `\fill[red] (3.26,-1.77) node[left] {\tiny{y\textsubscript{t}}} circle (1pt);`

Answer (score 1):

For some reason I get a mirrored version of your output, but you can just add whatever you like using Ti*k*Z methods.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[compat=1.1.0]{tikz-feynman}
\begin{document}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{feynman}
\vertex (a) {\(b\)};
\vertex [below= 2.4cm of a] (b){\(g\)};
\vertex [below right=of a] (c);
\vertex [ right=of c] (d) ;
\vertex [below right=1.0cm of d] (f3);
\vertex [below right=1.0cm of f3] (f4);
\vertex [above right=1.3cm of f3] (f5) {\(h\)};
\vertex [above right=1.3cm of d] (fw){\(W^{-}\)};

\diagram* {
(a) -- [fermion] (c) -- [fermion] (d),
(b) -- [gluon] (c),
(d) -- [fermion,edge label'=\(t\)] (f3) --[fermion,edge label'=\(t\)] (f4),
(f3)-- [scalar] (f5),
(d)--[boson] (fw),
};
\end{feynman}
\path (f3) node[red,circle,fill,inner sep=1.2pt,label={[red]below left:{$y_t$}}]{};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: it works. thank you.

Comment: @Winston If you want the top Yukawa to get closer to the vertex, use `\path (f3) node[red,circle,fill,inner sep=1.2pt,label={[red,inner sep=0pt]below left:{$y_t$}}]{};`.